# Is it Possible to Change "Edit Permissions" Based on a Field Value on that Node?

Tags: 7, users

I have users that need to be able to edit a piece of content they created until the status field on the piece content is updated to a particular value.

I've done some research and it looks like there are questions that are similar to mine but different enough that their solutions don't seem applicable.

I realize this question might be vague but I don't know how else to phrase it.

Are there any solutions to my problem?

Edit: I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: You should let us know what version of Drupal you are using (6,7,8?). It sounds like you may be looking for a workflow solution using something like [Workbench](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench), specifically [Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) can be used to set node permissions based on the publication status of a node, but that might be a different kind of "status" than you're talking about.

Comment: The status I'm talking about comes from a select list field on the form. Also I updated the question to include my version of Drupal. Currently looking into workbench!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by implementing `hook_node_access()` with a check on the particular field.

https://forumone.com/ideas/programmatically-restricting-access-to-drupal-content has a very similar use case (except the field there is an entityreference field to users, but you get the gist)

Comment: This looks great! I'll give it a shot and update when it's done.

Comment: Can this be applied solely to the edit content instead of blocking node access entirely?

Comment: As per [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x) the `$op` parameter can be "create", "delete", "update" or "view". So any